# Applying condition to only certain rows in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say i have following resultset:

```
col1   col2   timestamp

val1    1   2016-03-01 12:00:00
val2    1   2016-05-01 12:00:00
val2    1   2016-06-01 12:00:00
val2    2   2016-05-01 12:00:00
val2    2   2016-04-01 12:00:00
```

If i want to apply condition where i want to get rows where col2=1 and timestamp should be a max value. So for col2 = 1 i will only get below row
    `val2    1   2016-06-01 12:00:00`

I don't care about col2=2, for col2=2 i should get all the rows. I only want to apply above condition for col2 = 1. 
Is there a way we can do this in sql.

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY in JOIN statement :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
JOIN
(
   SELECT col2, MAX(timestamp) timestamp
   FROM table1
   WHERE Col2 = 1
   GROUP BY col2  
) A ON A.timestamp = table1.timestamp AND A.col2 = table1.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one option. You can window functions just for col2 with value 1.

```
SELECT COL1
    , COL2
    , TIMESTAMP
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COL2 != 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1
    , COL2
    , TIMESTAMP
FROM (
    SELECT COL1
        , COL2
        , TIMESTAMP
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) RNK
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE COL2 = 1
) TMP
WHERE RNK = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below query. This query is specific for your requirement:

```
select *
from table_name  t1
where ((t1.col2 = 1 
         AND t1.timestamp = (select max(timestamp)
                               from table_name t2
                               where t2.col2 = 1))
    OR (t1.col2 <> 1))
```